# GRUB bootloader not loading

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, gnome3, boot-loader, manjaro

I dual-booted Windows 10 with Manjaro and installed the GRUB bootloader in /dev/sda but no bootloader loads when system starts and it directly goes into Manjaro. I have to press F12 every time to go into Windows. How to fix it?

Comment: Well, there is a bootloader otherwise your system will not boot up. However, the GRUB menu is disabled. This is a broad question, Google it and you will find a solution.

Comment: google `grub how to add windows`

Answer (score 0):

First, don’t forget to backup.

Now the second thing I’d recommend, maybe just try:

`sudo update-grub`

I read about this issue on a [manjaro forum](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/solved-how-to-properly-restore-grub-with-efi-boot/75906/8) so might work. Maybe after the grub install, this command was not used?

To make sure that works, or after it doesn't,
the settings you are looking for are in `/etc/default/grub`
Use your favorite editor, vi or whatever to change the variable `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` to something other than zero seconds or use # to comment it out completely.

Now, make sure grub’s up to date: `sudo update-grub`

---

Also, I always like to provide ppl with exiting vi strategies so just fyi:
Hit the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to enter "Normal mode". Then you can type `:` to enter "Command-line mode".

- `:q!` to quit without saving (short for `:quit!`)
- `:wq` to write and quit